# I am trying to configure eclipse with ROS in Ubuntu when I try to " make ecliipse-project" for package it results into error

Tags: eclipse, ros

Note: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic) from Oracle virtualbox
here's what I am doing

```
cd catkin_ws
```

and then i create pckage

```
roscreate-pkg test std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

then `cd ..` and do `catkin_make`

then I got to test folder and do

```
make eclipse-project
```

but it generates the following error

```
mv Makefile Makefile.ros
if ! (cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -Wno-dev . && rm Makefile && rm CMakeCache.txt && rm -rf CMakeFiles); then mv Makefile.ros Makefile && echo "**ERROR building Eclipse project!**" && false; fi
-- Eclipse version is set to 3.6 (Helios). Adjust CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION if this is wrong.
[rosbuild] Building package tests
[rosbuild] Error from directory check: /opt/ros/melodic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py  /home/nis/catkin_ws/tests
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise Exception
Exception
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:99 (message):
  [rosbuild] rospack found package "tests" at "", but the current directory
  is "/home/nis/catkin_ws/tests".  You should double-check your
  ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the correct
  precedence order.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:177 (_rosbuild_check_package_location)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nis/catkin_ws/tests/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
**ERROR building Eclipse project!**
/opt/ros/melodic/share/mk/cmake.mk:45: recipe for target 'eclipse-project' failed
make: *** [eclipse-project] Error 1
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Have you carefully read each message? The one about `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` looks interesting.